# Android drawArc with shadow

Tags: android-canvas, android

I have a problem that when I draw an arc the shadow layer is not being drawn. Here's my `Paint` object:

```
circlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
circlePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
circlePaint.setShadowLayer(shadowRadius, 0, shadowOffset, 0xFF000000);
```

and in `onDraw()`:

```
canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, 180, false, circlePaint);
```

I have a feeling the shadowLayer is just being ignored. Is there any other way to draw a drop shadow around an oval? The problem is, that the oval get's resized (as in the height gets bigger), so I can't just use a ninepatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Paint.setShadowLayer` works only with text if hardware acceleration is enabled. To work around it you can just disable hardware acceleration for this particular view.

Comment: Oh yes that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep your view hardware accelerated, you can draw the arc with the shadow layer into an off-screen bitmap then draw that bitmap onto your canvas.

Comment: That's probably too slow - the arc will be stretched, so it has to be updated quite often

Comment: You can draw it once into the off screen bitmap and cache it.  Then on each onDraw call just draw the bitmap stretched instead of the arc.

Comment: No, the stroke of the arc has to stay the same, that wouldn't work with stretching a bitmap.

Comment: You're right, this will stretch the stroke of the arc and not yield desirable results.